# How would you allow users to extend off a Django site for templating purposes?

Tags: django

I'm building a Django site, and like a blog, I'd like users to further extend the content off the site by "skinning" through templates.

I'd like to re-use Django templating for this, I've been brainstorming on this but haven't gotten a solid idea how I can do this, can I hear some of your brilliant suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about users as site administrators who are using your program, or users as the actual users of the site the program is running on?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the cleanest way is to write really semantic HTML, allow various bits of it to be configured using [dbsettings](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/) (e.g. site names etc), then allow the user to add their own CSS file (perhaps by allowing the path to a CSS file to be managed through dbsettings).